# Can't install Ubuntu 18.04 alongside Windows 10, no option to install alongside

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I know this was asked before, but I can't seem to find a solution for Windows 10, I hope you understand. I have a Lenovo G400 laptop and I want to install Ubuntu 18.04 alongside the Windows 10 it already has, so I can choose the OS I want to run in at boot.

When I entered BIOS in the PC I could not select the USB which contained Ubuntu to boot it and install it.

When I went to the boot menu or something like that in my Lenovo and I chose the USB to boot from and ran Ubuntu with no problem at all! But when I headed on to installation, I got to the part in which you choose to erase the disk and install Ubuntu, install alongside Windows 10, or "something else". But surprisingly, the option to install alongside Windows 10 was not available!
How can I fix it? I really do not want to go to "something else"

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing 100% of your hard drive is configured for Windows, which is the default. You need to choose "something else", then you can use the disk manager to shrink the current Windows partition so you have available "unused" room to create an Ubuntu partition and install it in that new unused space.

Comment: Thanks!!
I have a ITB hard drive; and 8 GB of RAM, would this partition be fine?
SWAP: 10GB
EFI: 250MB
Root: 400GB
Thanks!!!